# Mono doesn't execute MacOS 11.1

Tags: mono, driver

When I start mono that I download it from [mono sites](https://www.mono-project.com) it runs for a moment and then closes with some error.

It says that: `The Carbon driver has not been ported to 64bits`

How can I update it?

Comment: You cannot. There is no official WinForms 64 bit support on macOS from Mono and probably won't in the future. Switch to other UI frameworks is your only option, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea

Comment: Thanks, you help me so much